# Boundary Condition of Electric Field(Zagwill's Problem 3.5)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics

I'm doing Problem 3.5 of Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics. In problem 3.15(b), the charge density is given by
$$\rho(x,y)=\rho _0e^{-k\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
I tried to let $\rho(s)=\rho _0e^{-ks}$ and put it into the Gauss's Law and get:
$$\frac{1}{s}\frac{d}{ds}(sE(s))=\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}e^{-ks}$$
By solving this differential equation, I got
$$E(s)=-\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0k^2s}(ks+1)e^{-ks}+\frac{c}{s}$$
, where $c$ is a constant determined by boundary condition. My problem is what boundary should I use.

Comment: I  used the integral form and get the same form with $c$ determined. I just want to try an alternative method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a definite integral

$\dfrac{1}{s}\dfrac{d}{ds}\left (sE(s)\right)=\dfrac{\rho_0}{\epsilon_0}e^{-ks}$

$\displaystyle \int_0^{sE(s)}  d\left (sE(s)\right) =\dfrac{\rho_0} {\epsilon_0} \int _0^s se^{-ks}ds$

$sE(s) = \dfrac{\rho_0} {\epsilon_0} \left[ \dfrac{1-e^{-ks}(ks+1)}{k^2}\right]$

$E(s) = \dfrac{\rho_0} {s\epsilon_0} \left[\dfrac{1-e^{-ks}(ks+1)}{k^2}\right]$

---

As an indefinite integral

$\displaystyle \int  d\left (sE(s)\right) =\dfrac{\rho_0} {\epsilon_0} \int se^{-ks}ds$

$sE(s) = \dfrac{\rho_0} {\epsilon_0} \left[ \dfrac{c-e^{-ks}(ks+1)}{k^2}\right]$

$E(s) = \dfrac{\rho_0} {\epsilon_0} \left[ \dfrac{c-e^{-ks}(ks+1)}{sk^2}\right]$

For small $s\quad e^{-ks} \approx 1-ks$

$E(s) \approx \dfrac{\rho_0} {\epsilon_0} \left[ \dfrac{c-(1-ks)(ks+1)}{sk^2}\right] = \dfrac{\rho_0} {\epsilon_0} \left[ \dfrac{c-1+k^2s^2}{sk^2}\right]$

As $s\rightarrow0\quad E(s) \rightarrow 0$ and so $c=1$

$E(s) = \dfrac{\rho_0} {s\epsilon_0} \left[\dfrac{1-e^{-ks}(ks+1)}{k^2}\right]$